# Android: How pixel density is calculate?

Tags: android, pixel

Today I saw the Nexus 7 [specifications](http://www.gsmarena.com/asus_google_nexus_7_(2013)-5600.php).
It has resolution of **1200 x 1920 pixels** and physical screen size of **4.49 x 7.87 inches**.

The specs says it has **323 density**. How did they calculated this number?

I been trying to do this:

```
1200 / 4.49 = 267.26
```

or this:

```
1920 / 7.87 = 243.96
```

But it doesn't get me anywhere. So where they getting this density value from?

Comment: Please read this...all of it. https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: @Squonk I am familiar with the programatic solution. It just the number does not much when I am trying to calculate it on paper. So I want to see an example of how its done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what I use when calculating "on paper":

http://labs.rampinteractive.co.uk/android_dp_px_calculator/

To calculate ppi:

ppi=(squareRoot(h^2+w^2))/inches

ppi=(squareRoot(1920*1920+1200*1200))/7

ppi=(squareRoot(3686400+1440000))/7

ppi=(squareRoot(5126400))/7

ppi=2264.155~/7

ppi=323.45~

Comment: I don't, why would you need it for? it's quite simple to make a calculator like this all you need to know is the ratios:
ldpi @ 1.00dp = 0.75px
mdpi @ 1.00dp = 1.00px
hdpi @ 1.00dp = 1.50px
xhdpi @ 1.00dp = 2.00px
rest is basic arithmetics

Comment: Check out the device specs. They say 323 dp. According to that 1.00dp = 0.00309px it doesn't sound right. This is what I am not getting, the numbers

Comment: 323dp are 646px for the xhdpi on the 1200x1920 nexus 7 (cuz theres another nexus 7 with only 800x1280) maybe you are confusing them. I really can't see whats your point for this yet.

Comment: I am trying to understand how do you get the number 323?

Comment: Just divide the px by 2. Simple as that.

Comment: I said 323dp are 646px, 1200px would be 600dp

Comment: Not according the phone specs as linked in the question.

Comment: So what you meant this whole time was how to calculate ppi -.- lemme edit the answer then...